# How to move my car automatically in the game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am developing a game in html 5 and canvas and new to game development.Now I have developed a game where there are few cars and few monsters are there and I can control the car by the below code:

```
update(){
        if (keys.ArrowUp) { // Player holding up
            this.y -= this.speed * frameTime;
            this.dir = Math.PI * 0; // set direction
        }
        if (keys.ArrowDown) { // Player holding down
            this.y += this.speed * frameTime;
            this.dir = Math.PI * 1; // set direction
          }
          if (keys.ArrowLeft) { // Player holding left
            this.x -= this.speed * frameTime;
            this.dir = Math.PI * 1.5; // set direction
        }
        if (keys.ArrowRight) { // Player holding right
            this.x += this.speed * frameTime;
            this.dir = Math.PI * 0.5; // set direction
        }        
        if(Math.sign(this.speed) === -1){ // filp directio of second car
            this.dir += Math.PI; // set direction
        }

        monsters.array.forEach(monster => {
            if(monster.isTouching(this)){
                monster.reset();
                monstersCaught += 1;
            }
        });
        if (this.x >= canvas.width || this.y >= canvas.height || this. y < 0 || this.x < 0) {
            this.reset();
        } 
    }
```

but now I want to make the cars move by themselves in different directions.I do not want to implement any routing paths or any AI . I just wanted to make the cars move by themselves in different directions.For example move straight for 3 seconds and then right for 2 seconds and down for 3 seconds and so on like that.This is my working [pen](https://codepen.io/RKR3/project/editor/ANBVpA/) .

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to move the other cars, or the users car?

Comment: The cars which are in the canvas.It is basically automating the game

Comment: you can use `setInterval()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there!

Simply add an parameter to your `update()` method to control your cars programmingly instead of using keyboard.  Make it `update(dir)`

```
 if (!dir && keys.ArrowUp) dir = 'up'  // Player holding up
 if (dir === 'up') {
        this.y -= this.speed * frameTime;
        this.dir = Math.PI * 0; // set direction
 }
```

then in your `updateObjects()`, call your auto cars with your new update function with direction

```
heros.array[2].update('left');
```

now this car will keep moving left!

**What about auto change directions?**

You can keep an internal value to track how long the car has been driving in the same direction, and what direction it is driving.  When it meets the `max` distance/time you set, let it select a new direction, also reset the tracker value!

```
this.traveled = 0;
this.currentDirection = 'left';
....
this.traveled += distance; // update the tracker 
....
if(this.traveled > 1000) { // wow we already traveled 1000px to the left, time to switch direction!
  this.currentDirection = 'right';  
  this.traveled = 0;
}
```

Checkout the updated pen with `.update('left')` and `.update('random')` for details : https://codepen.io/xna2/project/editor/XjQnqZ/

Comment: Yeah works like a charm and thanks for the valuable explanation